# Application routines stop while Form is open

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows forms application that is responsible for controlling the daily workload of my customer's employees, both while working at the office and while working at home. It's a Windows application that runs in two ways, as a service and as a taskbar icon that opens a simple window in which the employee can see his/her time limit of the day and ask for extra hours to his/her supervisor if needed.

Here is how the application should work: the application locks the user's pc if they exceed the permitted workload limit, and if the user thinks they might need some extra hours, they can unlock their pc (by entering their password), and in a time limit of 30 seconds click on the Taskbar's icon and use the application's commands to ask for extra hours.

The problem is: while the form window is open, the application's routines stop working, so if the user keeps it open the application won't lock the pc again, which can be treated as a breach in the system. Does anyone have an idea of what could be happening and something I could check in the system? Before you ask for code samples, it's a huge system and I'm not the first person to work on it, so I don't know where I should look (to be honest, I tried a lot of solutions, some found here in Stack Overflow).

This is the last thing I tried, but while the form is open it stops running as well.

```
if (Principal.Visible)
  Principal.Focus();
else if (Session.system_active)  
  Principal.ShowDialog();

aTimer.Interval = 30000;
aTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
aTimer.Start();
```

Comment: What is the type of `aTimer`.  There are several `Timer` classes in the Framework.  You'll want to use the Windows Forms one while in Windows Forms.  You will not be able to use it outside of Windows Forms though.  My suggestion, create an abstract ITimer interface that handles what you want it to do, and pick which implementation depending on your runtime environment.  FWIS, `Principal` isn't a good name; it has a standard meaning in .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.  That name confuses at least this reader

Comment: if `Principal.ShowDialog();` is running, it will block the code below it.  Maybe you meant `Principal.Show();` ?

Comment: Start the Timer before `.ShowDialog()`. I assume you stop the Timer and remove the event subscription in the `Tick` handler, which is also responsible for closing the Form.

Comment: Limit the time the form is open. If the user delays in asking for extra time, close the form.

Comment: Hello, I appreciate your help and want to thank you for spending your time helping me. But what I told about the timer is that it was an attempt t o solve the problem. The real problem is that the code inside the project stop working while the form is open, like if it was paused in visual studio. When the user closes it, it works again, if you know what I mean. It's something that didn't used to happen but it's happening now,

Comment: `ShowDialog()` [shows a Modal Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog) (Remarks section). When a [Modal Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes) is shown, the execution of the calling code is suspended. It will resume to the line after `ShowDialog()` when the Dialog is closed (and you should `Dispose()` of the Dialog). A Timer instead keeps Ticking, because it's created in a different Thread, which is then not blocked by the Dialog.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi, I did what you said and it worked!